# Moving text around in a div without moving the div

Tags: css, text, html, alignment

I have a div, inside the div is a background image that looks like a button and I have text in the div saying "Home". By default the text is snapped to the top and does not look right. How could I move the text around in the div without moving the div?

css file:
http://pastebin.com/xrAFMVDd

html file:
http://pastebin.com/b5Fubte0

Answer (score 20):

One way of doing this is to wrap your text in a `<p>` tag and use CSS attributes `top` and `left` with `position: relative` to specify the position of the text relative to the top left of the div.

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/zvMKH/

Comment: OOO! I really thought that was going to work but again... it moved the background with it. Maybe a different variation of what you did?

Comment: Hmm that's strange, it doesn't seem to be moving the background @ http://jsfiddle.net/zvMKH/1/  (you can play around the with left/top values to check)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include JUST the html/css for the div you're talking about?  You can paste right into your question and use the 'code' button to format it nicely.

Comment: its too big for the comment box. ill give you pastebin instead. html:http://pastebin.com/xuLqhWkk css:http://pastebin.com/QdPSkkk6 Remember we are editing the "Home" button.

Answer (score 8):

I fixed it by changing the `line-height` under `#button1 li a`. Worked like a charm! Thanks to everybody that contributed! I really appreciate it!

Comment: text-indent can be used to move the text horizontally without moving the background image